# Cannot restore files in GCS with versioning, when deleting folder

Tags: google-cloud-storage

For backups, I have set versioning in GCS.

Then I created folder and I put a file in the folder. After that, I've deleted the folder.

Then I used `gsutil ls -alr` command, but I cannot find the file in the bucket.

I found the folder, but I cannot restore the file in the folder.

When I delete a folder, why can't I restore a file in that folder even if setting versioning of GCS?

Answer (score 1):

Files in the Google Cloud Storage bucket that are archived and NOT live during the deletion of the folder remain in the archived list and can be retrieved.

For example you can:

1. Create a folder in bucket using Google Cloud Console: gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/example
2. Put a file to the folder using Google Cloud Console: gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/example/file_1.txt
3. Put another file to the folder using Google Cloud Console: gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/example/file_2.txt
4. Using the Google Cloud Console delete the `file_1.txt`
5. Using the Google Cloud Console delete the folder `example`
6. Run the command `gsutil ls -alr gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/example`

You will see a result as follows:

```
$ gsutil ls -alr gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/example
gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/example/:
        11  2019-02-27T11:48:54Z  gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/example/#1551268...  metageneration=1
        14  2019-02-27T11:49:49Z  gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/example/file_1.txt#1551268189...  metageneration=1 
TOTAL: 2 objects, 25 bytes (25 B)
```

You will notice that only the `file_1.txt` is available for retrial since it is the one that was archived and NOT LIVE when the folder was deleted.

Also, to list all the archived objects of the bucket you can run `gsutil ls -alr gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/**`.

So if your files were archived and deleted before the folder was deleted, you can list them using `gsutil ls -alr gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/**` and retrieve them using another command, for more info visit the [Using Object Versioning > Copying archived object versions](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/using-object-versioning#copy) documentation.